# Spring Roo says "Version is required for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin"

Tags: spring, maven, spring-roo

I am trying out Spring Roo 1.2.2 and can't get past this error:

> roo> hint
>
> Version is required for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

My maven version: Apache Maven 2.2.1

Appreciate any help.

**Update:**
Changing the directory and trying again makes it disappear! But I would still like to know what it was looking at, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always start roo in an empty directory (or already existing roo project directory) because the working directory is scanned by roo. In your case a POM is probably detected.
Also notice that roo becomes very slow when working from a "crowded" directory.

Comment: That was exactly the solution to my problem!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Roo 1.2.2 has issues working with maven plugin versions. You will need to make sure that all your plugin declarations in every module have version tag specified. Similar problem is described here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?132520-Multimodule-application-issue-Spring-Roo-1-2-2

Besides that I assume that you are trying to use Roo 1.2.2. on existing codebase. Than you need to follow this http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/existing.html

Although it is not said in this documentation, you possibly will need Maven 3 (3.0.4 comes with Roo/STS distribution) I suggest using this. It would be better first to migrate your project to Maven 3.

Comment: +1. **Explicitly specifying the version** of *maven-compiler-plugin* (despite the fact that it was configured in the parent POM) solved this issue.